# list in j2me client stub

Tags: web-services, hibernate, jakarta-ee, java-me, jax-ws

I create a web service that interact with database by hibernate.
the problem is:
when i want to create J2ME client stub, i receive some error(Unsupported tag in element jobs),
and i see my code and i found why that happen (it happen because in my Jobs entity i have a property type java.util.List but J2ME don't support list collection).
this is my Jobs entity:

```
public class Jobs implements java.io.Serializable{
private int id;
private String title;
private CompUsers compusers;
....
private Date publishDate;
private List requerment;
....
// geter and seter
}
```

my question is: how can i create J2ME client stub with this problem?